# Show Progressbar after pressing a button

Tags: button, display

I've recently struggling with Buttons. So I understand Buttons have the form `Button["text",action]`. Now I want the `action` to be some sort to function defined to show a progress bar, so I can achieve the effect of showing a progress bar after pressing the button, **inside** a 'Panel' of `DynamicModule` for example. (One answer pointed below can display the progress bar but it is displayed after `DynamicModule`, making it invisible if the content of `DynamicModule` is a full page)

Here is the simple code I have:

```
DynamicModule[{i = 0}, 
  Button["Show Bar", i++; SomeFunction[]]]
```

and the definition of some function:

```
SomeFunction[] := Monitor[Table[1; Pause[0.1], {j, 1, 10}], 
  ProgressIndicator[j, {0, 11}]]
```

If I run `SomeFunction[]` by itself, the progress bar shows nicely. If I click the button, though, I didn't see any thing. Any idea why? (Because I didn't specify how to display the output of the function?).

Thanks.

Comment: I found that by using a global variable g that records the progress and putting `Dynamic[ProgressIndicator[g,{1,100}]]` inside the `DynamicModule` is working... But this is not a good workaround if you have many , many such progress bars. And the problem is the progress bar will always be there.

Comment: "If I run SomeFunction[] by itself, the progress bar shows nicely...". It does not for me. But what is the goal? You wan to print `ProgressIndicator` each time? Where do you wan to print it?

Comment: @kuba  it works for me. Maybe you should try SomeFunction[]. The goal is to display a progress bar while the calculation is in progress. so the user will understand his computer is not freezing .After the calculation is done, the progress bar is removed and I have other actions to show.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Method -> "Queued"`:

```
SomeFunction[] := Monitor[Table[1; Pause@.1, {j, 1, 10}], ProgressIndicator[j, {0, 11}]]
DynamicModule[{i = 0}, Button["Show Bar", i++; SomeFunction[], Method -> "Queued"]]
```

or the following would be better in a concrete example:

```
DynamicModule[{i = 0, SomeFunction, something = "hello"}, 
  Panel@Column@{Button["Show Bar", i++; something = SomeFunction[];, 
    Method -> "Queued"], Dynamic@something}, 
  Initialization :> (SomeFunction[] := 
    Monitor[Table[1; Pause@.1, {j, 1, 10}], ProgressIndicator[j, {0, 11}]])]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. But it shows `NULL` after completing the progress bar if I add `;` after `Table` to suppress output. Any solution?

Comment: Your first code works great! without the Null issue.

Comment: Well, the `Null` issue has nothing to do with the first issue :) I just added the second example because it's a better habit to define everything inside `DynamicModule` :)

Comment: Thanks. But actually, this progress bar is not displayed within the `Panel`. It is displaying, but after the `Panel`.. This makes it not useful for a dynamic module that displays information inside a region...

Comment: So to this extent, it is not solving the problem..

Comment: @bboczeng Then you should specify your problem :) The first part of this answer answers your question above, now if you want everything properly set inside the `DynamicModule` it's an other story :)

Comment: OK.. I should make it clearer!